# get keys and values from a json data

Tags: jquery, json

```
  result=  {
        "_id": "5319b5e10748a6078fe4f360",
        "acces": "172.1.6.2.18",        
        "results": [{
            "\"test\":\"Connect_Disconnect\",\"os\":\"Windows NT\",\"report\":\"Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK<br>Verify the State is Disconnected:OK<br>Delete Profile to the Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK<br>\"": ""
        }],
        "tests": "Test01"
    }
```

while i trying to alert following

```
alert(JSON.stringify(result.results[0]));
```

am getting following data

```
{
    "\"test\":\"Connect_Disconnect\",\"os\":\"Windows NT\",\"report\":\"Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK<br>Add Profile to the Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Added Present on the Client:OK<br>Connecting to Access Point:OK<br>Verify the State is Connected:OK<br>Disconnecting from Access Point:OK<br>Verify the State is Disconnected:OK<br>Delete Profile to the Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK<br>\"": ""
}
```

from this how can i get the values of `test,os and report`

i tried

```
result.results[0].test
```

but getting value as `undefined.`

Here is the updated part

```
     $.get('/getStatus', getdata, function (data) {
           data.forEach(function (testreport) {
var report = JSON.stringify(testreport);
alert(report);

        }); 


      });
here alert prints



 {
        "_id": "5319b5e10748a6078fe4f360",
        "acces": "172.1.6.2.18",
        "adapter": "Win 10",
        "flavour": "VM-IE8-001-preq1",
        "id": "67",
        "os": "VM-WIN7-64",
        "results": [{
            "\"test\":\"Connect_Disconnect\",\"os\":\"Windows NT\",\"report\":\"Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK<br>Add Profile to the Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Added Present on the Client:OK<br>Connecting to Access Point:OK<br>Verify the State is Connected:OK<br>Disconnecting from Access Point:OK<br>Verify the State is Disconnected:OK<br>Delete Profile to the Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK<br>\"": ""
        }],
        "tests": "Test01"
    }
```

Comment: Seems `result.results` has 1 element, an object with 1 property with a long string as a property name: `"\"test\":\"Connect_Disconnect\",\"os\":\"Windows NT\",\"report\":\"Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK<br>Add Profile to the Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Added Present on the Client:OK<br>Connecting to Access Point:OK<br>Verify the State is Connected:OK<br>Disconnecting from Access Point:OK<br>Verify the State is Disconnected:OK<br>Delete Profile to the Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK<br>\""`.

Comment: ...where the property name contains quotes and colons and looks like JSON itself. That property's value (if you scroll way to the right) is an empty string `""`. You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/4KUVq/1/. In other words, your structure is technically valid but not what you need.

Comment: what does `alert(result._id+"");` return you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result.results it's a string, not a json.

check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4zT5P/2/)

```
var results = {
    "\"test\":\"Connect_Disconnect\",\"os\":\"Windows NT\",\"report\":\"Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK<br>Add Profile to the Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Added Present on the Client:OK<br>Connecting to Access Point:OK<br>Verify the State is Connected:OK<br>Disconnecting from Access Point:OK<br>Verify the State is Disconnected:OK<br>Delete Profile to the Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK<br>\"": ""
};


var resultsValid = {
    "test": "\"Connect_Disconnect\"",
    "os": "\"Windows NT\""
};


alert(results.test)

alert(resultsValid.test)
alert(resultsValid.os)
```

Check how are you generating this response

Also, you can verify json data on http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

it's an object, not an array.  there's no 0 index, just a hash or properties.  use this:

`result.test`

Comment: yea i tried ur code also.but getting value undefined

Comment: i have updated my question.Please have a look at this

Comment: @Sush try JSON.parse instead of JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try using `getJSON()` method of jquery, and implement it this way:

```
$.getJSON( "enterYourUrlHere", function( result ) {
    alert(result.results[0].test)
});
```

And, Yes ofcourse, @Mate is correct.